# Passing Handler between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm running some Threads on a main activity, and while those threads are running, I'm creating a sub activity to show the results of the Threads.

Main activity is notified about the results of the Threads via Handlers (even its state is `onPause()`, because of running sub activity). I wanna do the same thing between the main activity and the sub activity as follows:

I pass another handler from sub activity to main activity by calling `((MainActivity) getParent()).setMainActivityHandler(handler)` to initialize a handler in the main activity, where `setMainActivityHandler()` is just an initializing method of a handler in the main activity. Then when the Thread send a `Message` to the main activity via their handlers, main activity will send the same massage or modified version of another `Message` to the sub activity via another handler. So, sub activity will update the view according to this message's content.

However, `((MainActivity) getParent())` returns `null`. How I can I manage to do this. Is there any other method?

**PS:** Both activities extend Activity. Manifest file has intent filter for main activity (`action.VIEW` & `category.DEFAULT`), NO intent filter for sub activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a straight handler, you want to be using a `Messenger` for this, which is designed for inter-process/activity messaging.

The way I do this is with a Service running that binds to whatever activity is running and sends messages to it based on the background task, but I think you could save having to do this.

You could try declaring a static messenger in your second activity, initializing it when the sub-activity is created and only sending messages to it from the main activity when the static messenger is not null (null it out when pausing/destroying that sub-activity, or track statically if it is shown or not)